# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type int and string using Asp.net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating a simple inventory system in Asp.net MVC

I have got an error at this line below

`int db_product = db.products.First(e => e.id == m.barcode_id);`

Comment: One of those values (id or barcode_id) is an int, and one is a string, as stated by the error message. So you cannot compare the two. You will need to cast the string to an int, or the int to a string, to be able to compare them.

Comment: yes e.id should be interger. barcode_id is string . so how to cast it sir

Comment: The simplest way is with `int.Parse(m.barcode_id)` but it depends on what you expect the ID to be. It would always have to be a number for that to work. This might not be compatible with your database context if you're using entity framework for example.

Comment: int db_product = db.products.First(e => e.id.ToString()== m.barcode_id);
Since you said barcode_id is a string, just convert your e.id to string and compare.

Comment: int db_product = db.products.First(e => e.id.ToString() == m.barcode_id);  i did sir  but i got the Error Cannot implicitly convert type  to Int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments noted, the error really says it all.  One of your variables is an `int` and one is a `string` so they cannot be directly compared.  You need to convert either the `int` to a `string` or the `string` to an `int`, I would do the latter in this case but both can work.  Something like this could work:

```
var db_product = db.products.First(e => e.id.ToString() == m.barcode_id)
```

Comment: if i write it like this way db.products.First(e => e.id.ToString() == m.barcode_id) it is working sir but   int db_product = db.products.First(e => e.id.ToString() == m.barcode_id);
                        db_product.qty = db_product.qty - m.qty;          if i write it int db_product = like this error  i need this variable to do the calucation  db_product.qty = db_product.qty - m.qty;  like this

Comment: It is hard to understand what you need based on that comment but why can't you do `db_product.qty = db_product.qty - m.qty; ` on the next line?  The first line find the product you need and the next calculates the new qty value.

Comment: yes sir. The first line find the product next calculates the new qty value.

Comment: Oh, actually your first problem is that you used `int db_product` but the thing you are getting is _not_ an int, it is a `product` from your `products` table.  Change the `int db_product` to be `var db_product` as I just did in my edit, then add the second line where you do the subtraction.